# How should I crop out a non-rectangular, non-polygon ROI in opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I would like to crop out a non-rectangular, non-polygon part of an image, which has words I will then process with OCR.

I have managed to find the contour of the object, which looks like this:
[image: contour]

I need the resulting crop to be as exact as possible, hence I can't use methods that approximate a polygon or rectangle.

Here is the input image and code:

[image: input image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils

shape = cv2.imread("testImg.jpg")
resized = imutils.resize(shape, width=600)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(resized,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
th3 = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

cv2.imshow("th3",th3)

#find contours of thresh
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(th3, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
print("Number of Contours found = " + str(len(contours))) 

#a black screen
out = np.zeros_like(resized)
#copy of thresh
copy=th3.copy()

#find largest contour area and draw it
cntArea = []
for c in contours:
    cntArea.append(cv2.contourArea(c))
maxArea = max(cntArea)
maxIndex=cntArea.index(max(cntArea))
maxCnts=contours[maxIndex]
cv2.drawContours(out, maxCnts, -1, (0,255,0), 2)

cv2.imshow("out",out)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

I've tried clearing out the background contours, but it would not work because of my OCR detection method (the image below would not pass through my OCR code)

[image: cleared out background]

Comment: It looks like you are looking for a solution that uses a mask. What is going to be the data structure for storing the "cropped" result? Question is not clear because image is black inside and outside the contour.

Comment: Please post your code and your input image.

Comment: Data structure? I would want the pixels in the contour to be pasted on a black screen (isolate whatever's in the contour and add to a np.zeroes_like matrix)

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a mask of the desired area were every pixel inside the contour will get value 1 and the pixels outside the contour will get value 0. You can do this by using cv2.drawContours function, set thickness=cv2.FILLED. With color = (1, 1, 1)
2. Use the mask to multiply with the original image. `final_img = mask * original_img`